# Docker registry management UI

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have the registry v2 container and docker_auth up and running. The registry uses self sign certificate which was created with my CA.I can push and pull images without any issues and everything else is working fine.

But I would like some sort of GUI to manage it.

Can somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: are you looking for https://hub.docker.com/r/portainer/portainer

Comment: No, it is used for managing cluster. i am looking for UI for managing images in  private docker registry

Comment: what about this https://hub.docker.com/r/joxit/docker-registry-ui/